# Suggestions for settings.php - Local dev, Development server, Live server

Tags: workflows, configuration, staging

Basically, one of the greatest questions of all time: What are some ways you're using settings.php in your development/staging workflow?

Right now, I have my settings.php file set up like the following, and I base my development on the server's $HOST directive—meaning I can work on dev.example.com for the development (shared) server, local.example.com for my local computer (and other dev's local code checkouts), and www.example.com (or just example.com) for the live site.

(This code is in the 'Database settings' section of settings.php):

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$base_url = 'http://'.$host;
$cookie_domain = $host;

switch($host) {
  case 'example.com': # Production server
    $db_url = 'mysqli://prod_sql_user:password@127.0.0.1/prod_db';
    $update_free_access = FALSE;
    $conf = array (
      // Set production config options here...
      'example_setting' => 0,
    );
    break;

  case 'dev.example.com': # Development server
    $db_url = 'mysqli://dev_sql_user:password@127.0.0.1/dev_db';
    $update_free_access = FALSE;
    $conf = array (
      // Set production config options here...
      'example_setting' => 0,
    );
    break;

  case 'local.example.com': # Local server
    $db_url = 'mysqli://local_sql_user:password@127.0.0.1/local_db';
    $update_free_access = FALSE;
    $conf = array (
      // Set production config options here...
      'example_setting' => 0,
      // Turn off most core caching.
      'cache_inc' => 'includes/cache.inc',
      'cache' => CACHE_DISABLED,
    );
    break;

}
?>
```

This works pretty well for most purposes, but it means we have a lot of extraneous code sitting around in our shared settings.php file... is there a better way?

Comment: You should use Drupal multi-site solution https://www.drupal.org/node/290768

Answer (score 66, accepted):

What I do is separating that file into a settings.php and a local.settings.php.

At the end of settings.php is the following code:

```
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/local.settings.php')) {
  include dirname(__FILE__) . '/local.settings.php';
}
```

The local file is then excluded from whatever VCS you are using. The advantage is that you can put settings which are common over all instances in settings.php and have that versioned/distributed automatically and keep the local stuff in local.settings.php.

Comment: This is actually the strategy used on drupal.org itself and we use consistently at Palantir.net. For a bikeshed, I recommend using 'settings.local.php' as the filename as it matches the pattern set by 'settings.default.php'.

Comment: Ha, I actually wrote settings.local.php but copy & pasted the code sample from an actual settings.php which had local.settings.php in it so I changed it back ;)

Comment: I've created a gist for this: https://gist.github.com/1235389

since i've been using this more and more frequently

Comment: Note: Drupal 8 has now added a similar snippet to the settings file by default, you just need to uncomment it: http://drupal.org/node/1118520

Comment: @DaveReid: the pattern is set by '[default.settings.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites!default!default.settings.php/7)' not by 'settings.default.php'.

Comment: This is rather obvious, but a simple gotcha is that if you copy settings.php to create override files, make sure to remove the include section from the end of the file!

Comment: A couple years later, and this is the way I'm doing things for shared-development projects, more or less. `settings.php` has all the normal/default settings inside, but a developer can add local changes by simply creating `local.settings.php`. And Drupal 7's `sites.php` configuration file can help devs use whatever local hostname they want to point to a site folder.

Comment: For funsies you could use `(__DIR__)` instead of `dirname(__FILE__)`.  [They are equivalent](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).

Comment: this also works the same way with less code: `@include('local.settings.php');` (if it's in the same directory which mine is)

Answer (score 25):

This seems like you're reinventing Drupal's built in multisite functionality.

Personally, I keep all standard themes and modules for the site in `sites/all`, and then have `sites/dev.example.com` and `sites/example.com`.

As an added bonus you can then have different `files` folders for each site, and you can add any development modules to `sites/dev.example.com/modules` as well.

Comment: That makes some sense, but I have a few sites where there are 5-10 multisite folders already, and having all the themes for those sites in sites/all/themes can be quite annoying. Not to mention my typical use of custom.module for each site. I guess I could use sitename_custom.module instead :-/

Comment: You could always try using symbolic links from the `sites/dev.example.com/modules` to `sites/example.com/modules`

Comment: Accepting this answer - I'm going to try this on the site I'm currently working on. Looks like a good fit for my workflow.

Comment: I think this is actually a poor way to handle dev and staging environments because they aren't actually different/separate sites, just different versions of the same site. In this case you would very much want to avoid having separate files for each site.

I'd very much recommend using the method mentioned below where settings.php is versioned and settings specific to each site (DB settings) are put in a local.settings.php that is not versioned.

Comment: @Mikey P - both solutions are valid—I think it's mostly up to personal/team preference here... there are tradeoffs with either approach, in my opinion.

Comment: @Mikey P: Using the method above means that everything is shared between the 2 sites. The only things that are different are the `settings.php` files, and both of those can be kept in version control.

Comment: Agree with MikeyP completely. If the goal is to have as identical an environment as possible between dev, staging, and production then we wouldn't want to use the multisite method.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to ignore the file locally (using a `.gitignore` file in git) and then keep separate versions if the file on each host.

Comment: This is an interesting solution, though I do like tracking settings.php in git (some bugs I've had crop up are due to setting.php changes...). Is there a way I could have my local git checkout replace that file with my own (besides having me copy in my own file)?

Comment: That's what I do too. Files with configuration data, especially with database credentials have no place in the VCS.

Comment: @geerlingguy yes you can. Please read my update (if it'll be published ;)

Comment: @martin I agree, but let's don't forget we can have SPECIAL separate repo only for THIS file! You can read it in my update.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to always set up DNS or host file entries and use

```
dev.example.com
staging.example.com
```

and

```
example.com
```

Then I have completely separate settings file directories with differing files directories. For instance ./sites/dev.example.com/files

Comment: The problem I see with that approach is that I often have a /themes/ and /modules/ directory that I use for each site (often in a multisite setup), and since I need to use those site-specific modules and themes for local, dev and production, I can't just do hosts/multisite like that :-/

Comment: Good point. I guess I left out that I symlink that stuff in.

Comment: You can create a symlink and share themes and modules folders that way. So basically you main folder will be a production folder and then from it you can create a symlinks to stage and dev and local.

Answer (score 5):

Why not have a few folders based on the development host name?

Example

- sites/dev1.domain.com
- sites/dev2.domain.com
- sites/dev3.domain.com
- sites/www.domain.com

Each with their own settings file and db_url.

Comment: Potential problem: Files saved/uploaded in one site folder will not be accessible to another.

Comment: See my reply to @Stewart :)

Comment: Create symlinks to the central files folder

Answer (score 2):

If the only things changing are the database credentials, then you can set environment variables in your local (and staging/production) virtual host config or in a .htaccess a folder above your web root. Here's a simple example:

`/var/www/example.com/drupal-resides-here`

I can then create a .htaccess file here:

`/var/www/example.com/.htaccess`

which has the following code:

```
SetEnv DB1_USER my_local_user
SetEnv DB1_PASS my_local_pass
SetEnv DB1_HOST my_local_host
SetEnv DB1_NAME my_local_dbname
```

Then in `/var/www/example.com/drupal-resides-here/sites/default/settings.php` (or whatever) you can grab the db credentials like:

`$db_url = "mysql://{$_SERVER['DB1_USER']}:{$_SERVER['DB1_PASS']}@{$_SERVER['DB1_HOST']}:{$_SERVER['DB1_PORT']}/{$_SERVER['DB1_NAME']}";`

This lets multiple developers run things locally and you can push to staging / production while still tracking settings.php (there are more things in there than just the database credentials...). You also wouldn't have to keep track of multiple settings.php files.

Comment: I personally think this is the best way to go. However, our set up we add the SetEnv statements to the apache config. Makes it a bit more secure.

Comment: That's an interesting use for .htaccess and variable storage. But what about when you run `drush up --y`? That will overwrite your base .htaccess file.

Comment: This is done in an `.htaccess` file a level above webroot. For example, `/var/www/.htaccess` stores these directives, and `/var/www/drupal/.htaccess` would be Drupal's `.htaccess`. You could also just put it in the Apache virtual host configuration, which is even nicer. Regardless of any of that, we almost always have custom stuff in the webroot's `.htaccess` and therefore if we update Drupal we need to compare the `.htaccess` changes with Git.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and most efficient solution that is just one line is the following. Just include it in the last line of your settings.php file:

```
@include('settings.local.php');
```

The @ symbol in the front just means don't display any error even if it doesnt find that file. Typical setup's like this involve a conditional to check if the file is there. This accomplishes it in one line without it.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Also known as the **STFU PHP operator**.

Comment: Simple, but I don't think the most efficient. http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance