# Easy database reconfiguration for migration

Tags: 7, database, migrations, configuration, testing

I have build a Drupal site on my local development server and I am preparing to move it to my test server and eventually my live server.  I know where to find the database settings in my settings.php file, but there only appears to be one set of database configurations.  I would like to know if there is a good way to include three different database settings in my settings.php file, one for my development environment, one for my test server and one for my live server.  I could simply add a settings section to the file for each and simply comment out the ones that I am not using, but I would like to use an automatic solution, one that can either allow me to specify a setting for all three locations, or tries each setting until it finds a setting that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Berdir wrote about a very nice solution](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/41/9379) some time ago, which also made it into Drupal 8 now.

It means that you keep separate settings.php's, which are included whenever available with a small code snippet.

Comment: Looks good.  It first I considered this to be 'hacking core' but it's not because the file exists in the sites folder.  Also, Drupal.org does it, so it must be a good solution.